# I tried to change the function many times and I keep getting the same error

Tags: python, pycharm

Anyone can help, please!!

```
Ack = exp_seq_num
        clientSocket.sendto(Ack.encode(), (serverName, serverPort))              #Sending the POSITIVE ACK to the server after encoding it.
        Ack_checksum = hashlib.md5(Ack.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        Ack_checksum = str(Ack_checksum)
        clientSocket.send(Ack_checksum.encode(), (serverName, serverPort))
        incoming_file.write(incoming_data)    

**This is the message error:**
   clientSocket.send(Ack_checksum.encode('utf-8'), (serverName, serverPort))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sendto` and `send` in exactly the same way, while [docs for socket interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) clearly show that they take different arguments.

`send` only takes bytes you want to send as an argument.